# URL rewrite rule to remove trailing slash after query string

Tags: url-rewriting

we have people coming to the website with trailing slash at the end of the URL e.g **https//www.domain.com/page?name=john&name=doe/**

for some reason, the logic to read query string parameters in code fails if there is a trailing slash at the end of the query string. Is there any way I can write a rule to check if there is trailing slash at the end of the query string them remove it.?

Answer (score 0):

```
RedirectRule ^(http.+?\.com\/.+?\?.+?)\/$ $1
```

This should work, but not sure what rewrite regex format you need on iirf before entering to your page. I am using iirf.ini on my aspx C# project.

^...$ - asserts position at start and end of a line

.+? - match any char with quantifier one and unlimited, lazy

\. \/ \? - escape character for regular expressions

$1 - group 1 from the regex first bracket